# Exception when casting object to string on different machine

Tags: java, exception, casting, objectinputstream

When trying to cast from an Object, (which should be a serialised string)  to a String, on one machine it works fine, but on another it brings up an exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Both machines run the same versions of Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) and the same version of Java (1.7.0_51).
Code is as follows,

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
while(true)
    {
        data = (String) ois.readObject(); //Error Here
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```

The object input stream works successfully over sockets, and the whole program runs well on other machines (even with different version of linux and Java). Watching for TCP traffic indicates that the string is being sent correctly. What could cause this to happen, and is there any way to make this work universally?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you send data to the socket?

Comment: Not sure why Juned got downvoted, but he is right in pointing out that the OP is trying to convert an Array of Objects to a String.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I didnt downvote, but his answer was obvious.. and the OPs question was more like how it can return an object only on a particular machine while returning string on others...

Comment: What if the object being sent across the wire is *actually* a serialized array?  That would be one reason that I could see this exception being raised.

Comment: Please read this link about serialization. This may solve your problem.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#whyserial)

Comment: I had the same problem and it disappeared after restarting eclipse and doing a clean-build,

Answer (score 0):

While I have no idea why the same code would perform differently on two supposedly similarly configured machines, I'd propose changing your code to read to an object and then only cast it to a string if you know it is one. If it isn't...and you aren't expecting that, then you can log it, throw an exception or do something else that is of use.

So maybe something like;

```
while(true)
{
    object obj = ois.readObject(); 
    if (obj instanceof String)
    {
        data = (String) obj;
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    else 
    {
        // Do whatever makes sense here for you
        // If you are testing, then maybe dump whatever info you
        // can to a log file to help you understand what you are reading
        // from the socket and how you could handle that gracefully in 
        // a production environment.
    }
}
```